# Both monitors not working simultaneously. one with USB c and another with HHDMI

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi, external-display, usb-c, docking-station

My Dell dock can't take VGA cable from monitor so I used a USB-C to VGA adapter to connect to the dock and simultaneously my another monitor with HDMI connected to dock. But I'm just seeing a screen with USB-C is on but not the another. And when I disconnect the USB-C then only I can see the screen with HDMI is working.  Can you help me with solution how I can use both monitors at a time ?

Comment: Have you confirmed from the both the computer's and dock's documentation that they can support 2 external displays simultaneously?

Comment: Have you checked both monitors are visible in the OSes display configuration?

Comment: Video cards have a limit to the total number of pixels that they can drive. You need to first tell us whether your computer is capable of doing what you want it to do by providing the specific model of the computer and dock.

Answer (score 0):

Windows key + p and select extend or expand? Or else go to Windows display settings

Comment: I dont know what the name is in english, never used windows set to english

Comment: It is Extend, from what I remember. The options are (from memory): single monitor only, extend, duplicate, 2nd monitor only